# What exactly does continuity of the homotopy function mean?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

It is my understanding that given two continuous maps $f,g:X\to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, we say $f$ and $g$ are homotopic if there exists a **continuous** homotopy function $\Phi:X\times[0,1]\to Y$ such that $\Phi(x,0)=f(x)$ and $\Phi(x,1)=g(x)$. What exactly does *continuous* mean for the $\Phi$ function in this definition?

I understand that generally, continuity means that the preimage of an open set is open, but if we use this definition, what exactly does openness mean in $X\times[0,1]$? $X$ is a topological space, so obviously we have some well defined notion of openness $\tau_X$ for $X$, and for $[0,1]$ we can use the usual metric definition of openness (letting Euclidean distance be our metric) which defines open sets to be those sets where all points are the center of a positive radius ball contained in the set. But then what is the convention for defining openness in $X\times[0,1]$ in a situation like this? Is there some canonical construction of a "product topology" that is commonly used in situations like this without explicit mention?

Comment: Yes there is. Did you do a quick search for "product topology"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the *product topology* which is a basic construct in general topology. The product of topological spaces $(A_i,\tau_i)$ is defined as
$$(A_1,\tau_1) \times (A_2,\tau_2) =(A_1 \times A_2,\tau_p)$$
where $U \in \tau_p$ if and only if for each $a = (a_1,a_2) \in U$ there exist $U_i \in \tau_i$ such that $a \in U_1 \times U_2 \subset U$. In other words, a basis for $\tau_p$ is given by all products of open subsets of the $A_i$.

See any textbook on general topology or [Product topology - definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310559/product-topology-definition). In this forum you will find a lot of information about the product topology. Search for this phrase:

https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=product+topology